# How to configure IPTables to accept http from a single IP in inbound, allow DNS in outgoing directions and block everything else?

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, http

I am trying to configure IPTables to accept http connection from 10.0.0.1 only and reject everything else. When I make http connection from 10.0.0.1, it is blocked. I am facing another issue. I am trying to allow DNS in outgoing direction and block everything else. The problem is when I use OUTPUT DROP everything is dropped

Here is what I did

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your output chain is that you allow packets to go out towards port 53 for dns.
But the response is dropped because you didn't specify a rule for established connections.

Add:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Same goes for your input chain.

Comment: So I will add this rule this then drop all output?